# React app on S3 bucket not working and Access Denied when trying to sync S3 on the command line

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I followed an AWS tutorial to create an S3 bucket place a react app into it and ran into a ton of problems. Here are two:

I was able to manually upload the files that are in the build folder after running npm run build. However, the app doesn't display correctly when I go to the URL. It gives me some 404 errors in the console.

[image]

The second is that I would like to be able to use the sync command to push from the command line. The problem is that I get an access denied error.

```
aws s3 sync build/ s3://storygraf-react
fatal error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
```

I have confirmed that I am logged in under the right credentials. I came across some other tutorials that claimed that you need some additional policies within the S3 bucket to allow for the sync from the command line. The problem is that entering those policies results in a very unhelpful error.

Here is what I have tried, along with basically every variation on this. Most tutorials are incorrect and leave off the principal or something.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1626945244527",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::storygraf-react/*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::storygraf-react/*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::storygraf-react/*"
    }
]
```

}

I'm pretty frustrated that a basic tutorial leaves me in this position with no real help or explanation. This seems like something that should have been a slam dunk.

Comment: Your comment that "Most tutorials are incorrect and leave off the principal or something" suggests that you are confusing S3 bucket policies (which require a principal) with IAM policies (which do not require, or even allow, a principal).

Comment: Maybe that is where I am confused. Do I need to alter the bucket policy or do I need to alter a user policy? It seems confusing that you can alter a user to without altering the bucket?

Comment: In the typical case (and I don't know which tutorial you are referring to) the S3 bucket policy would allow uauthenticated s3:GetObject access to the HTML/JS/CSS content in the S3 bucket while an IAM policy would allow the site maintainer (you, an IAM user) to manage content in that same bucket.

Comment: That seems to be where I am confused. You can set a bucket policy that allows read access to all and then a user policy that allows that user to manage content on the bucket? You don't have to set a bucket policy allowing that user those rights?

Comment: Correct, there is no requirement for the bucket policy to allow an IAM principal to access the bucket. It's sufficient for that IAM user to have policies (directly or via group membership) that permit S3 access to the bucket. *Some* AWS resources do require both a resource-level policy on one end and an identity-level policy on the other end, for example KMS keys, but most (in fact almost all) do not.

Comment: This is really confusing to me. Thought that this policy gave the iam user all the access needed?

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::storygraf-react/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246627/discussion-between-jarmod-and-joshua-foxworth).